# how to go to another page after clearing the scratchpads?

Tags: javascript, redirect, scratchcard

I need to go to the next page when all the scratchpads are cleared but it doesn't work. 
here i haven the code it is about it's long but it's like nine time the same code just for another scratchpad.

```
var cleared = 0;

//scratchpad1
var images = [], 
index = 0;

images[0] = "images/slide1.jpg";        //de plaatjes die je kunt vrij krassen
images[1] = "images/slide2.jpg";
images[2] = "images/slide3.jpg";
images[3] = "images/logo.jpg";
images[4] = "images/winner.png";
images[5] = "images/scratch-to-win.png";

index = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);

$('#nummer1').wScratchPad({
  scratchMove: function (e, percent) {
    console.log(percent);
    if (percent > 70)
    {
        this.clear();
        cleared++;
    }
  }
});
$("#nummer1").wScratchPad('bg', images[index]);
$("#nummer1").wScratchPad('fg', 'images/overlay.png');      //de laag die je weg krast
$("#nummer1").wScratchPad('size', '15');                //grote van het vlak dat je ineens weg krast
$("#nummer1").wScratchPad('cursor', 'url("./images/coin.png") 5 5, default');  //de muis die je hebt boven het krasveld


//scratchpad2
var images = [], 
index = 0;

images[0] = "images/slide1.jpg";
images[1] = "images/slide2.jpg";
images[2] = "images/slide3.jpg";
images[3] = "images/logo.jpg";
images[4] = "images/winner.png";
images[5] = "images/scratch-to-win.png";

index = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);

$('#nummer2').wScratchPad({
  scratchMove: function (e, percent) {
    console.log(percent);
    if (percent > 70)
    {
        this.clear();
        cleared++;
    }
  }
});
$("#nummer2").wScratchPad('bg', images[index]);
$("#nummer2").wScratchPad('fg', 'images/overlay.png');
$("#nummer2").wScratchPad('size', '15');
$("#nummer2").wScratchPad('cursor', 'url("./images/coin.png") 5 5, default');

//scratchpad3
var images = [], 
index = 0;

images[0] = "images/slide1.jpg";
images[1] = "images/slide2.jpg";
images[2] = "images/slide3.jpg";
images[3] = "images/logo.jpg";
images[4] = "images/winner.png";
images[5] = "images/scratch-to-win.png";

index = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);

$('#nummer3').wScratchPad({
  scratchMove: function (e, percent) {
    console.log(percent);
    if (percent > 70)
    {
        this.clear();
        cleared++;
    }
  }
});
$("#nummer3").wScratchPad('bg', images[index]);
$("#nummer3").wScratchPad('fg', 'images/overlay.png');
$("#nummer3").wScratchPad('size', '15');
$("#nummer3").wScratchPad('cursor', 'url("./images/coin.png") 5 5, default');

//scratchpad4
var images = [], 
index = 0;

images[0] = "images/slide1.jpg";
images[1] = "images/slide2.jpg";
images[2] = "images/slide3.jpg";
images[3] = "images/logo.jpg";
images[4] = "images/winner.png";
images[5] = "images/scratch-to-win.png";

index = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);

$('#nummer4').wScratchPad({
  scratchMove: function (e, percent) {
    console.log(percent);
    if (percent > 70)
    {
        this.clear();
        cleared++;
    }
  }
});
$("#nummer4").wScratchPad('bg', images[index]);
$("#nummer4").wScratchPad('fg', 'images/overlay.png');
$("#nummer4").wScratchPad('size', '15');
$("#nummer4").wScratchPad('cursor', 'url("./images/coin.png") 5 5, default');

//scratchpad5
var images = [], 
index = 0;

images[0] = "images/slide1.jpg";
images[1] = "images/slide2.jpg";
images[2] = "images/slide3.jpg";
images[3] = "images/logo.jpg";
images[4] = "images/winner.png";
images[5] = "images/scratch-to-win.png";

index = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);

$('#nummer5').wScratchPad({
  scratchMove: function (e, percent) {
    console.log(percent);
    if (percent > 70)
    {
        this.clear();
        cleared++;
    }
  }
});
$("#nummer5").wScratchPad('bg', images[index]);
$("#nummer5").wScratchPad('fg', 'images/overlay.png');
$("#nummer5").wScratchPad('size', '15');
$("#nummer5").wScratchPad('cursor', 'url("./images/coin.png") 5 5, default');

//scratchpad6
var images = [], 
index = 0;

images[0] = "images/slide1.jpg";
images[1] = "images/slide2.jpg";
images[2] = "images/slide3.jpg";
images[3] = "images/logo.jpg";
images[4] = "images/winner.png";
images[5] = "images/scratch-to-win.png";

index = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);

$('#nummer6').wScratchPad({
  scratchMove: function (e, percent) {
    console.log(percent);
    if (percent > 70)
    {
        this.clear();
        cleared++;
    }
  }
});
$("#nummer6").wScratchPad('bg', images[index]);
$("#nummer6").wScratchPad('fg', 'images/overlay.png');
$("#nummer6").wScratchPad('size', '15');
$("#nummer6").wScratchPad('cursor', 'url("./images/coin.png") 5 5, default');

//scratchpad7
var images = [], 
index = 0;

images[0] = "images/slide1.jpg";
images[1] = "images/slide2.jpg";
images[2] = "images/slide3.jpg";
images[3] = "images/logo.jpg";
images[4] = "images/winner.png";
images[5] = "images/scratch-to-win.png";

index = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);

$('#nummer7').wScratchPad({
  scratchMove: function (e, percent) {
    console.log(percent);
    if (percent > 70)
    {
        this.clear();
        cleared++;
    }
  }
});
$("#nummer7").wScratchPad('bg', images[index]);
$("#nummer7").wScratchPad('fg', 'images/overlay.png');
$("#nummer7").wScratchPad('size', '15');
$("#nummer7").wScratchPad('cursor', 'url("./images/coin.png") 5 5, default');

//scratchpad8
var images = [], 
index = 0;

images[0] = "images/slide1.jpg";
images[1] = "images/slide2.jpg";
images[2] = "images/slide3.jpg";
images[3] = "images/logo.jpg";
images[4] = "images/winner.png";
images[5] = "images/scratch-to-win.png";

index = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);

$('#nummer8').wScratchPad({
  scratchMove: function (e, percent) {
    console.log(percent);
    if (percent > 70)
    {
        this.clear();
        cleared++;
    }
  }
});
$("#nummer8").wScratchPad('bg', images[index]);
$("#nummer8").wScratchPad('fg', 'images/overlay.png');
$("#nummer8").wScratchPad('size', '15');
$("#nummer8").wScratchPad('cursor', 'url("./images/coin.png") 5 5, default');

//scratchpad9
var images = [], 
index = 0;

images[0] = "images/slide1.jpg";
images[1] = "images/slide2.jpg";
images[2] = "images/slide3.jpg";
images[3] = "images/logo.jpg";
images[4] = "images/winner.png";
images[5] = "images/scratch-to-win.png";

index = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);

$('#nummer9').wScratchPad({
  scratchMove: function (e, percent) {
    console.log(percent);
    if (percent > 70)
    {
        this.clear();
        cleared++;
    }
  }
});
$("#nummer9").wScratchPad('bg', images[index]);
$("#nummer9").wScratchPad('fg', 'images/overlay.png');
$("#nummer9").wScratchPad('size', '15');
$("#nummer9").wScratchPad('cursor', 'url("./images/coin.png") 5 5, default');

if (cleared === 9)
{
    window.alert('alle vakjes zijn open gekrast');
    window.location.href="geenprijs.php";
}
```

this is what i have tried but it didn't work.

Comment: "It didn't work." - how didn't it work? What did you expect to happen, which bit(s) of code do you expect to do that, what have you tried?

Comment: it was supposed to give an alert with some text and if you click on ok you would go to another page. but there comes no alert